# Electronic Power Selecting Switch

Tags: power-supply, transistors, diodes, switches, buck-boost

I have a circuit which works with a battery normally. The nominal voltage of battery is 3.7 V and I am using boost converter to make it 5 V. And I have a charging circuit of this battery too. So, my aim is when the USB cable plugged, I want to boost circuit stop working. So, it is like a switch controlled by a 5 V. Like normally closed relay.

How can I do this? I tried MOSFET and BJT transistors at the input port of the boost circuit but these are caused voltage drop.

As a result, how can I disconnect 3.7 V from boost circuit when 5 V is plugged?

Boost circuit:
[image]

Charging Circuit:

[image]

USB input:

[image]

Comment: Are you dead set on using the 34063 or could you consider a (modern) DC/DC with EN-pin? That would make the task much simpler. Also probably more efficient...

Comment: Read the application note on [Adding shutdown feature to MC33063A, MC34063A
switching regulators](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slla339/slla339.pdf)

Comment: Why don't you make your boost circuit provide 4.9 volts and just connect the 5 volts from USB directly to Vcc. The action of raising Vcc by 0.1 volts should cause the boost circuit to shut-down into fairly low power (if that is enough for you?).

Comment: @Finbarr Yes in the file that you shared there is a load switch to do that, How can I simulate this ic? I can not find the LTSpice symbol of it. Can I simulate it on altium? I am new in altium

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out with adding diodes and selected another regulator which has enable pin.
The circuit is below.

[image]